# ungzip data receiving from server

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, gunzip

An API call giving me `data` as response and this data is `gzipped` `string`.
How I can `ungzip` this data and get the original string back as NSString in my iOS App.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look for approach or directly [use this solution](https://github.com/nicklockwood/GZIP), and then convert unzipped data to NSString.